# How to use Express.js and http.createServer function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following Node.js code:

```
var app, fs, express
fs = require("fs")
app = require("http").createServer(function (req, res) {
  var file
  file = req.url === "/" ? "/index.html" : req.url
  console.log(req.method + " " + file)
  return fs.readFile("./views" + file, function (err, data) {
    if (err != null) {
      res.write(404)
      return res.end("<h1>HTTP 404 - Not Found</h1>")
    }
    res.writeHead(200)
    return res.end(data)
  })
})
app.listen(3000, function () {
  return console.log("running...")
})
```

I need to include Express.js in my application, for example:

```
app = express()
express = require("express")
app.use(express.bodyParser())
app.use(app.router)

app.get("/form", function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile("./form.html")
})

http.createServer(app).listen(3000)
```

How to combine those two snippets?

Comment: look for `function(req, res) { ... }` and put the code you want inside that? and follow an express tutorial

Comment: Your basically creating a middleware,.. just use  `app.use(function (req, res, next) { /*do stuff*/  next(); });`  Instead of doing your 404, if you don't handle it, just call `next()`.   You can also call `app.use` on a route,  `app.use('views', function (req, res, next) {})`.

Comment: Also if your views are always in format `/views/viewname` you can also use the app.get with parameters.  eg.  `app.get('/views/:viewname', function(req, res, next) { /*req.params.viewname==view*/ })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By joining 2 code in one , i guess you want to use the middleware you described in 1st file

```
 var app = express();
 var express = require("express");
 app.use(express.bodyParser());
 app.use(app.router);

 app.get("/form", function (req,res){
  res.sendfile("./form.html");
 });

app.use(function(req, res) {
 var file;
 file = req.url === '/' ? '/index.html' : req.url;
 console.log(req.method + " " + file);
 return fs.readFile("./views" + file, function(err, data) {
 if (err != null) {
    res.write(404);
   return res.end("<h1>HTTP 404 - Not Found</h1>");
 }
res.writeHead(200);
return res.end(data);
})

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

Comment: Why would you put the request handler for `/` and `index.html` in middleware?  Those should be an express routes.  And, the code should be used `res.sendFile()`.  The point of using Express is to use the capabilities it has built in, not to avoid them.

Comment: Also, there doesn't appear to be any reason to have `app.use(app.router);` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create app with Express
let app = express();
// Create a Node server for Express app
let server = http.createServer(app);

// Parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));

// Parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.get("/form", function (req,res){
  res.sendfile("./form.html");
});

app.use(function(req, res) {
  var file;
  file = req.url === '/' ? '/index.html' : req.url;
  console.log(req.method + " " + file);
  return fs.readFile("./views" + file, function(err, data) {
  if (err != null) {
         res.send(404);
  }
  res.json(data);
})



server.listen(3000);
```